# Change Isolation level of a transaction in Reactive Postgres Client (Quarkus)

Tags: java, kotlin, vert.x, quarkus

I want to execute some dql/dml queries in a transaction with the isolation level `READ_UNCOMMITED`.
I'm using the reactive postgres client with mutiny with the suggested method `withTransaction()` from the [Quarkus docs](https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-sql-clients#transactions), but I couldn't find any way to change the isolation lvl.

Is that possible, and if yes how can I achieve this ? Thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [change the isolation level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-set-transaction.html) by executing a SQL query:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```

Comment: I expected a more elegant solution then just executing a raw sql query, but seems like the only way to do it. Thank you !